# Problems printing .tiff files using ggsave

Tags: r, macos, ggplot2, tiff

I am trying to print .tiff files and am getting an error here is an example:

```
ratings <- qplot(rating, data=movies, geom="histogram")
qplot(length, data=movies, geom="histogram")
ggsave(file="length-hist.tiff")
```

This code produces this error:

```
Saving 7 x 7 in image
Error in grDevices::tiff(..., width = width, height = height, res = dpi,  : 
  argument "antialias" is missing, with no default
```

What am I doing wrong? I am using R version 2.15.0 for Mac OS X Leopard and ggplot 0.9.0

Comment: What is the result of `capabilities()["tiff"]` for you? If it is not `TRUE`, then your installation of R can not create TIFF files.

Answer (score 0):

With ggplot2 0.9.1 and R version 2.14.1  on Linux, your code works and I can't reproduce this problem. Maybe you should try updating ggplot2?